# SQL Server DETACH databases older than 6 months

Tags: sql, sql-server, detach

I can retrieve a list of databases created more than 6 months ago like this:-

```
-- all databases over 6 months old
select name, crdate
from sys.sysdatabases
where crdate <= DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())
      AND name not in ('master','model','msdb','tempdb','distribution')
```

Gives results like this:-

```
name        crdate
db1         2008-06-25 09:01:11.747
db2         2008-06-25 09:01:50.967
```

I can detach a database like this:-

```
-- detach database
EXEC master.dbo.sp_detach_db @dbname = N'db1',
@keepfulltextindexfile = N'true'
```

I need to run `sp_detach_db` for each database the first query returns.

What's the best way of doing this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a cursor for the task:

```
declare cur cursor for
select name
from sys.sysdatabases
where crdate <= DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())
and name not in ('master','model','msdb','tempdb','distribution')

declare @name nvarchar(200)

open cur

fetch next from cur into @name

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_detach_db @dbname = @name, @keepfulltextindexfile = N'true'
    fetch next from cur into @name
end

close cur
deallocate cur
```